# Converting datetime to specific format

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Been trying to figure out why a sql function I have written results in a sum of 0 when I include (AM/PM) in the formatting of the call.

```
SELECT Label, SUM(Diff)
FROM (
        select distinct mr.deviceid, TO_CHAR(mr.ReadDate, 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:00 AM') AS Label, (MAX(ComputedReading) - MIN(ComputedReading)) AS Diff
        from reading as mr
         WHERE mr.ReadDate >= DATEADD(hour, -100, GetDate()) AND mr.ReadDate <= GetDate() and mr.orgunitid = 1
         group by mr.deviceid, label
         order by label desc
     ) as ReadData
GROUP BY Label
ORDER BY Label
```

what I noticed was that when I modified the label to :

```
TO_CHAR(mr.ReadDate, 'MM/dd/yyyy')
```

then It would actually provide me with a sum.

Not quite sure why adding am and pm would stop this.

Any idea

computedreading is an int type
readdate is a datetime type

Comment: I am guessing you are using postgres and not sql server? TO_CHAR is NOT a sql server function.

Comment: I'm using redshift which I guess is postgres?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Regardless of DBMS though, generally you should be doing the formatting of the data at the presentation layer, not data.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name just missed the "s". ;)

Comment: Computed reading is an int. I am just trying to find the difference each day for the devices in an org

Comment: reddate is a datetime object

Answer (score 0):

Try using `TO_CHAR(TRUNC(mr.ReadDate), 'MM/dd/yyyy')`.  It looks like your intent is to get mr.ReadDate @ 12:00 AM and TRUNC will do exactly that.

Comment: what about trying to get 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:00 AM'

Comment: I am also trying to support each hour of the day

Comment: I tried to do TO_CHAR(TRUNC(mr.ReadDate), 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:00 AM') but this did not include the hours. defaulted to 12:00